# add string to string array and display last/previous string in that string array

Tags: android

i want to add the current string in a textview view to a string array in arrays.xml.then display the last/previous string of that array in a textview (setText).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify `arrays.xml` at runtime -- sorry! You will need to modify an in-memory `ArrayList` or something instead.